# Count available unique combinations when each option has a limit

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations

I need algorithm that count's available unique combinations, but I can't wrap my head around it. Let's say I have multiple categories and each category have multiple options and then each option has limit how many times it can be used.

For example:

**Shape**

- Rectangle (4)
- Triangle (3)
- Circle (2)
- Hexagon (1)

**Material**

- Wood (5)
- Stone (3)
- Metal (2)

**Color**

- Blue (7)
- Green (2)
- Red (1)

There can be different number of options in each category, but the sum is contstant (10 in this example).

Now I need to count how many possible unique combinations can be there.

Let's say first combination is rectangle, stone, red.
Now balance for each option should be reduced by 1 and red should be removed from available options in color category.
Next combination is hexagon, metal, green. Hexagon is removed from shape category and so on...

In the end function should return number of available unique combinations.

Comment: Hi! Extremely interesting problem. I assume you want an optimal solution, as opposed to a greedy one for instance?

Comment: Hi @Stef. For now I think any solution would be good. Dataset is quite small so I don't think I would run into serious performance issues.

Comment: By "optimal solution" I meant the exact maximum possible number of unique combinations. As opposed to an approximate algorithm that would maybe find a high number of unique combinations, but would not be guaranteed to find the highest possible number.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, you're right.

Comment: When you say "unique combinations", do you mean that the combinations are unordered, or that the triplets in a combination must be different?

Comment: Hi @rici. I  mean that if there is for example combination rectangle-wood-blue, it cannot be repeated. There may be rectangle-wood-red, rectangle-wood-green and etc.

Comment: Ok, that's not an obvious interpretation of what you wrote. What for you is a "combination"?

Comment: In other words, what are you counting? Triples consisting of shape/material/colour? Collections of ten triples? (Ordered or not ordered? Complete or possibly incomplete?)

Comment: @rici My interpretation is that we want to arrange the 30 elements into 10 bins, where each bins contains exactly 1 shape, 1 material and 1 colour. Then count how many distinct bins there are. The actual number of distinct bins depends on how we arranged the items, and the goal is to maximise the number of distinct bins.

Comment: BTW, found by random trial: `(10, {('rectangle', 'stone', 'blue'), ('hexagon', 'wood', 'blue'), ('rectangle', 'wood', 'blue'), ('rectangle', 'metal', 'green'), ('triangle', 'stone', 'blue'), ('circle', 'wood', 'green'), ('triangle', 'wood', 'blue'), ('circle', 'stone', 'blue'), ('triangle', 'wood', 'red'), ('rectangle', 'metal', 'blue')})`